# abstract, extends and creating instance issue

Tags: java, instance, abstract-class, abstract, extends

`Klasse1` is a abstract class and has a `foo()` method. `Klasse2` extends `Klasse1` and has a `doo()` method but don't overwrite the `foo()` method.

Why I cannot call `doo()` method in `Tester` class?

**Klasse1.java**

```
public abstract class Klasse1 {
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Klasse1");
    }
}
```

**Klasse2.java**

```
public class Klasse2 extends Klasse1 {
    public void doo() {
        System.out.println("Klasse2");
    }
}
```

**Tester.java**

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Klasse1 k;
        k = new Klasse2();
        k.foo();
        k.doo(); // doesn't work
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `Klasse1` doesnt have `doo()`

Comment: @Rehman that is `troo`

Comment: You have a reference type if Klasse1, so at that time, you only know what Klasse1 can do/

Comment: @schwobaseggl did you mean true ?? :)

Comment: @Rehman Hmm... with all the `foo` and `doo`, I have no `cloo` ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

At compile time Java compiler checks reference type instead of instance type.

In this case reference type is `Klasse1` which doesnt have `doo()`. Hence it will throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

`Klasse1` doesn't have `doo` method so it's natural.

You can cast that to your `Klasse2` and then use that like this:

```
((Klasse2)k).doo();
```

Answer (score 0):

`K` is an object of the class `Klasse2` but referenced as `Klasse1`,

`K` can call all methods that `Klasse1` declared, and can call all methods that `Klasse2` declared if is casted to that class.

## Example:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Klasse1 k;
        k = new Klasse2();
        k.foo();
        ((Klasse2)k).doo(); // now works
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem!